# iOS binary data column not showing up in Sqlite database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Hi everyone I have the following setup:

[image: data]

This is my definition

```
@interface Item : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * cid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * image_data;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * image_url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * order_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * url;
```

Yet somehow I only see the following in my sqlite3 database:

```
sqlite> .schema ZITEM
CREATE TABLE ZITEM ( Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Z_ENT INTEGER, Z_OPT INTEGER, ZCID INTEGER, ZORDER_ID INTEGER, ZSTATUS INTEGER, ZIMAGE_URL VARCHAR, ZTITLE VARCHAR, ZURL VARCHAR );
```

Anyone here knows why there isn't a ZIMAGE_DATA as one of these columns?

Comment: Have you perhaps got external storage enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Find out whether the value of image_data is still there after a fetch. That'll give you an idea about whether the value is being kept elsewhere, like external storage.

Also, make sure **Transient** is not set for the attribute.